# Reasons for NullPointerException on pm.makePersistent()

Tags: google-app-engine, nullpointerexception, jdo, junit4, datanucleus

I’m getting hopeless on this. Modelling a simple one-to-many relationships with Google App Engine with JDO. I have a class that "has" a few kinds of other child classes in basic `java.util.Set<ThatOtherClass>`. But there comes the confusing part: I have one pretty complex class with a lot of methods, some static fields and methods, which behaves well when added to the parent class in a Set. But, then, when I try to add a new related class, it just fails to persist in a JUnit 4 test, using all the local datastore helpers to set the environment (working properly, tested with other classes). This is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.PersistenceCapableMapping.postInsert(PersistenceCapableMapping.java:1039)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager.runPostInsertMappingCallbacks(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:218)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager.access$200(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:49)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager$1.apply(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:117)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager.storeRelations(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:82)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreFieldManager.storeRelations(DatastoreFieldManager.java:959)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.storeRelations(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:585)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertPostProcess(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:320)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjects(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:272)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:256)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3185)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.makePersistent(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3161)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1298)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1175)
at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:669)
at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:694)
at mypackage.MyTests.myTest(MyTests.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The exception is getting thrown from the line where I call `pm.makePersistent(parentObject)`, the object itself is properly initialized, as I notice that only simply adding `@Persistent(mappedBy = "foreign_key") private OtherClass otherClassObject;` makes the unit test fail on that line, removing it makes it pass again.

I also tried to rewrite the other class (still fails), and even just copy-paste the code of the working child class (which surprisingly doesn’t fail). That all makes me wonder: what could possibly be different about the more complex child class that I can use it in a Set and not the other one?

Yes, I followed https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships for JDO 2.3 (owned one-to-many).

I have just a few more suspicions left what could cause the problem, one of which is some stale cache of the DataNucleus enhancer (I still use the older 1.0 plugin with DataNucleus 1.1). Moreover, I am not sure whether the problem is in the target class or the parent class, but the more complex child class works with the very same relationship definition, so that makes me think it’s the target child class. Doesn’t matter what the value of the relationship is at the `pm.makePersistent()` call time, as the exception happens no matter what the value is in it – I tried it a lot of times. If it could be some dirty cache, how to clear it? I couldn’t even find the DataNucleus logs.

The simpler non-working child class looks basically like this, stripped of every data as I needed to be sure where is the problem (and didn’t help myself much):

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Version;
import javax.jdo.annotations.VersionStrategy;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
@Version(strategy = VersionStrategy.VERSION_NUMBER)
public class TestChild
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;

    @Persistent
    private Parent parent;

    public void setParent(Person parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Parent getParent()
    {
        return this.parent;
    }
}
```

And the field on the other side of the relationship:

```
@Persistent(mappedBy = "parent")
private Set<TestChild> testChildren;
```

Can anybody help me, please? I spent hours on this :-(

Comment: I just noticed, moreover, a lot more confusing thing:

    `if (pc != null)
        {
            if (relationType == Relation.ONE_TO_ONE_BI)
            {
                StateManager otherSM = sm.getObjectManager().findStateManager(pc);
                AbstractMemberMetaData relatedMmd = mmd.getRelatedMemberMetaDataForObject(clr, sm.getObject(), pc);
                Object relatedValue = otherSM.provideField(relatedMmd.getAbsoluteFieldNumber());`

The last one is the line which throws NullPointerException from the stack trace, so I guess relatedMmd is null. `Relation.ONE_TO_ONE_BI`?!

Comment: A few more notes I forgot to mention: GAE 1.6.6, HR datastore.

Comment: Have you already tried to use a more recent version of datanucleus? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2#Migrating_to_Version_2.0_of_the_DataNucleus_Plugin

Comment: Not yet, as it’s “an experimental, innovative, and rapidly changing new feature”… Not sure if that is suitable for production environment, and totally not sure if it would solve such an easy problem as owned one-to-many relationship.

Comment: This so called "experimental" plugin passes way more tests than v1.0 (and Google know that) and doesn't fail any that 1.0 passes. It's been available for the last 8+ months. All tests are in public SVN. The simple fact is that the DataNucleus project gives no support for ancient versions, whereas the new plugin uses current (supported) code. You choose ...

Comment: I didn’t know that! Okay, will try to switch to it and see if it works. Now hunt down the correct build.xml for transition…

Comment: I just tried a simple unit test with very simple parent and child classses and it passed, no NullPointerException. Can’t really see what caused all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the exact same as what you posted but this issue 
http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=165
has the same exception and was fixed in the new plugin (v2.0+) in Sept 2011.

Comment: I’ve seen that page. Almost successfully switched to the v2.0+ plugin, but now need to figure out why 0 classes get enhanced… :-(

Comment: Aaah made it, just some mess from included .jars of the old version. Now lets see if it’s fixed.

Comment: Now we’re at: `WARNING: javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Class org.datanucleus.api.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass was not found.` (nice, warning, but fatal exception…)

Comment: Switched to ...JDOPersistenceManagerFactory in the same package. But still the build.xml from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2#Migrating_to_Version_2.0_of_the_DataNucleus_Plugin keeps including old jars. Did Google guys even test the file?

Comment: Have you read the following page ? http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/UpgradingToVersionTwo

Comment: Not yet, wish I had earlier, would save me hours of configuring ant build.xml…

Comment: Will probably use it to exchange ant for Eclipse’s buttons and shine. Anyway, thanks for the tip with upgrading to v2, the relationship now seems to work as expected!

Comment: Followed the instructions from that page, but ran into a whole other problem, added it as a comment below the page. But so far, ant runs well, only this makes troubles (Eclipse).